# To Store value in variable via text box

Tags: plugins

In my plugin i want the user will enter data.For that  i have created two text box and a submit button so that the value i enter in text box will store in variable available in my plugin. one varible is $d and other is $p. But my value which i am entering in textbox is not storing in variable. please help...

```
function board_admin(){  // Main php file
include('settings.php');
} //file in which i have created text box

function pu_create_plugin_tables() //function to auto create table on plugin activation
{
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'board';
if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
  post varchar(3) DEFAULT 10,
  post varchar(3) DEFAULT 10
);";

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
}
} 
// Settings.php
<form action="data.php" method='post'>
<input type="text" name="border_post" placeholder="No. of posts" />
<input type="text" name="border_day" placeholder="No. of days" />
<input type="submit" name="post_submit" value="Submit" button="button_primary">
//data.php
<?php
global $wpdb;
$p = $_POST['border_post'];
$d = $_POST['border_day'];
 $wpdb->insert($table_name, array( 'post' => $p, 'day' => $d ), array( '%s', '%s'   ) )
?>
```

Comment: where do you save the option? also this: `'showposts=$p'` won't work, variables don't expand in single quoted strings.

Comment: Previorsly i thought of saving options in phpMyAdmin table of a database. But latter i thought if i save in phpMyAdmin then plugin will works only in my wordpress. it will not be universal. So currently i am cnfused about where to save options.